# mainPanel unable work in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Question 1 : I tried to apply **shinyDashboard** package but there has no datatable display...

[image: ShinyDashboard UI]
[image: ShinyDashdoard Server]

```
## Creating a parallel computing Cluster and support functions.
## Preparing the parallel cluster using the cores
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 16)
pkgs <- c('shiny','shinydashboard','magrittr','plyr','dplyr','googleVis','quantmod','TTR','lubridate','DT','purrr')
suppressMessages(require('BBmisc'))
suppressMessages(lib(pkgs)); rm(pkgs)

## Set the googleVis options first to change the behaviour of plot.gvis, so that only the chart 
##  component of the HTML file is written into the output file.
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')

tickers <- sort(c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
                  'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
                  'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
                  'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK'))

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
            titlePanel('Stock Price'),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    helpText('Select the stocks to examine. Information will be collected from Google/Yahoo finance.'),
                    checkboxGroupInput('counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers), 
                    actionLink('selectall', 'Select/Unselect All'),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    dateRangeInput('dates', 'Date range', start = '2013-01-01', end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
                    checkboxInput('log', 'Plot y axis on log scale', value = FALSE),
                    checkboxInput('adjust', 'Adjust prices for inflation', value = FALSE)),
                mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel( #tabBox
                        tabPanel('Table', dataTableOutput('table1'), 
                                 downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
                        tabPanel('Chart', htmlOutput('gvis')))
                )))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
        else if(input$selectall%%2 == 0){
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers)
        }else{
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers, selected = tickers)
        }
    })

    getCounter <- function(){
        tickers <- c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
                 'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
                 'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
                 'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK') %>% sort
        data <- llply(tickers, function(x) {
            y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
                tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'google', auto.assign = FALSE)), error = function(e) 
                    data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA)))); 
            if(nrow(na.omit(y))==0) {
                y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
                    tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)), 
                             error = function(e) data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA))))
            }else{
                y %<>% mutate(Date=as.character(rownames(.)), Weekday=factor(weekdays(ymd(Date))));
                names(y) <- c('Com', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Date', 'Weekday')}; 
            y}, .parallel=TRUE) %>% rbind_all %>% tbl_df %>% 
            select(Date, Weekday, Com, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) %>% mutate(Com=factor(Com))
        return(data)
    }

    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
        data <- getCounter()
        df <- as.data.frame(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter & Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]));
        dt <- datatable(df, 
                        caption="Table 1.1.1 : Public Listed Companies Stock Price",
                        extensions = list("ColReorder"=NULL, "ColVis"=NULL, "TableTools"=NULL
                                          #, "FixedColumns"=list(leftColumns=2)
                        ), 
                        options = list(autoWidth=TRUE,
                                       oColReorder=list(realtime=TRUE), #oColVis=list(exclude=c(0, 1), activate='mouseover'),
                                       oTableTools=list(
                                           sSwfPath="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                                           aButtons=list("copy", "print",
                                                         list(sExtends="collection", sButtonText="Save",
                                                              aButtons=c("csv","xls")))),
                                       dom='CRTrilftp', scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                                       colVis=list(exclude=c(0), activate='mouseover')))
        return(dt)
    })

    output$gvis <- renderGvis({
        data <- getCounter()
        smp <- subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                          Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2])
        if(input$adjust) smp <- adjust(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                                                  Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]))
        if(input$log) smp <- mutate(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter, 
                                           Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]), 
                                    Low=log(Low), Open=log(Open), Close=log(Close), High=log(High))
        gvisCandlestickChart(smp, xvar='Date', low='Low', open='Open', close='Close', high='High', 
                             options=list(legend='none', gvis.editor="Edit me!"))
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), display.mode='showcase')
```

Above codes is not workable (Notes: the **selectall** function SUDDENLY unworkable without edit anything). While it is workable on normal Shiny with mainPanel without shinydashboard... Somebody shade me a light?

```
# server.R

suppressMessages(library('BBmisc'))
pkgs <- c('shiny', 'shinythemes', 'shinyjs', 'shinyBS', 'shinydashboard', 'shinyAce', 'quantmod', 
          'TTR', 'plyr', 'dplyr', 'magrittr', 'stringr', 'purrr', 'googleCharts', 'lubridate', 
          'googleVis', 'DT', 'sparkline', 'zoo')
suppressMessages(lib(pkgs))
rm(pkgs)

tickers <- c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
             'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
             'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
             'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK') %>% sort

data <- llply(tickers, function(x) {
  y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
    tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'google', auto.assign = FALSE)), error = function(e) 
      data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA)))); 
  if(nrow(na.omit(y))==0) {
    y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
      tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)), 
               error = function(e) data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA))))
  }else{
    y %<>% mutate(Date=as.character(rownames(.)), Weekday=factor(weekdays(ymd(Date))));
    names(y) <- c('Com', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Date', 'Weekday')}; 
  y}, .parallel=TRUE) %>% rbind_all %>% tbl_df %>% 
  select(Date, Weekday, Com, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) %>% mutate(Com=factor(Com))

#'@ googleChartsInit(chartTypes = c("ALL", "annotatedtimeline", "area", "bar", "bubble", "calendar", "candlestick", 
#'  "column", "combo", "gauge", "geo", "geomap", "intensitymap", "line", "map", "motion", "org", "pie", "sankey", 
#'  "scatter", "steppedarea", "table", "timeline", "treemap"))
## =================================================================================================

#'@ shiny::runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Example"),
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText('Select the stocks to examine. Information will be collected from Google/Yahoo finance.'),
      checkboxGroupInput('counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers), 
      actionLink('selectall', 'Select/Unselect All'),
      br(),
      br(),
      dateRangeInput('dates', 'Date range', start = '2013-01-01', end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
      br(),
      checkboxInput('log', 'Plot y axis on log scale', value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput('adjust', 'Adjust prices for inflation', value = FALSE)),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('Data', dataTableOutput('table1'),
                 downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
        tabPanel('Plot', htmlOutput('gvis')))
    ))#'@ ,

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
      else if(input$selectall%%2 == 0){
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers)
      }else{
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers, selected = tickers)
      }
    })

    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter & Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]),
        caption="Table 1.1.1 : Public Listed Companies Stock Price",
        extensions = list("ColReorder"=NULL, "ColVis"=NULL, "TableTools"=NULL
                          #, "FixedColumns"=list(leftColumns=2)
                          ), 
        options = list(autoWidth=TRUE, 
                       oColReorder=list(realtime=TRUE), #oColVis=list(exclude=c(0, 1), activate='mouseover'),
                       oTableTools=list(
                         sSwfPath="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                         aButtons=list("copy", "print",
                                       list(sExtends="collection", sButtonText="Save",
                                            aButtons=c("csv","xls")))),
                       dom='CRTrilftp', scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                       colVis=list(exclude=c(0), activate='mouseover')))
    })

    output$gvis <- renderGvis({
      smp <- subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                      Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2])
      if(input$adjust) smp <- adjust(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                                            Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]))
      if(input$log) smp <- mutate(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter, 
                                         Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]), 
                                  Low=log(Low), Open=log(Open), Close=log(Close), High=log(High))
      gvisCandlestickChart(smp, xvar='Date', low='Low', open='Open', close='Close', high='High', 
                           options=list(legend='none', gvis.editor="Edit me!"))
    })
  }
#'@ ))

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Shiny apps]

Question 2 : By the way, there has another error on piper function when I posted to rstudioconnect and shinyapps deployment website. I tried to not use piper function but the rstudioconnect keep showing **No function %>% found.** message.

[image: Piper Error]

Comment: Question 1: question is unclear given your example code seems to work. Question 2: what does your log say at [https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/)

Comment: The coding is work without ShinyDashboard... any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
 a <- as.data.frame(subset(... ..) #your code
)
a }, options <your code>)
```

Comment: output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    df <- as.data.frame(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter & Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2])); df},
    dt <- datatable(df, ...))) # DT::datatable()
    return(dt)
  )


##
## Changed but same, blank output...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @RYOENG: Please put shinydashboard code instead of the images, so that it can be easily reproducible at my end.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I added the source codes for both with and without shinydashbord... Its work without shinydashboard but I just would like to use shinydashboard to make whole shinyapp user friendly. Kindly look into this?

Answer (score 0):

```
## Creating a parallel computing Cluster and support functions.
## Preparing the parallel cluster using the cores
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 16)
pkgs <- c('shiny','shinydashboard','magrittr','plyr','dplyr','googleVis','quantmod','TTR','lubridate','DT')
suppressMessages(require('BBmisc')); suppressMessages(lib(pkgs)); rm(pkgs)

## Set the googleVis options first to change the behaviour of plot.gvis, so that only the chart 
##  component of the HTML file is written into the output file.
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')

tickers <- sort(c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
                  'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
                  'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
                  'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK'))

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidPage(
            titlePanel('Stock Price'),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    helpText('Select the stocks to examine. Information will be collected from Google/Yahoo finance.'),
                    checkboxGroupInput('counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers), 
                    actionLink('selectall', 'Select/Unselect All'),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    dateRangeInput('dates', 'Date range', start = '2013-01-01', end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
                    checkboxInput('log', 'Plot y axis on log scale', value = FALSE),
                    checkboxInput('adjust', 'Adjust prices for inflation', value = FALSE)),
                mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel( #tabBox
                        tabPanel('Table', dataTableOutput('table1'), 
                                 downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
                        tabPanel('Chart', htmlOutput('gvis')))
                )))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
        else if(input$selectall%%2 == 0){
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers)
        }else{
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers, selected = tickers)
        }
    })

    getCounter <- function(){
        tickers <- c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
                 'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
                 'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
                 'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK') %>% sort
        data <- llply(tickers, function(x) {
            y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
                tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'google', auto.assign = FALSE)), error = function(e) 
                    data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA)))); 
            if(nrow(na.omit(y))==0) {
                y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
                    tryCatch(suppressAll(getSymbols(x, src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)), 
                             error = function(e) data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA))))
            }else{
                y %<>% mutate(Date=as.character(rownames(.)), Weekday=factor(weekdays(ymd(Date))));
                names(y) <- c('Com', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Date', 'Weekday')}; 
            y}, .parallel=TRUE) %>% rbind_all %>% tbl_df %>% 
            select(Date, Weekday, Com, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) %>% mutate(Com=factor(Com))
        return(data)
    }

    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
        data <- getCounter()
        df <- as.data.frame(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter & Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]));
        dt <- datatable(df, 
                        caption="Table 1.1.1 : Public Listed Companies Stock Price",
                        extensions = list("ColReorder"=NULL, "ColVis"=NULL, "TableTools"=NULL
                                          #, "FixedColumns"=list(leftColumns=2)
                        ), 
                        options = list(autoWidth=TRUE,
                                       oColReorder=list(realtime=TRUE), #oColVis=list(exclude=c(0, 1), activate='mouseover'),
                                       oTableTools=list(
                                           sSwfPath="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                                           aButtons=list("copy", "print",
                                                         list(sExtends="collection", sButtonText="Save",
                                                              aButtons=c("csv","xls")))),
                                       dom='CRTrilftp', scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                                       colVis=list(exclude=c(0), activate='mouseover')))
        return(dt)
    })

    output$gvis <- renderGvis({
        data <- getCounter()
        smp <- subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                          Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2])
        if(input$adjust) smp <- adjust(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter &
                                                  Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]))
        if(input$log) smp <- mutate(subset(data, Com %in% input$counter, 
                                           Date>=input$dates[1] & Date<=input$dates[2]), 
                                    Low=log(Low), Open=log(Open), Close=log(Close), High=log(High))
        gvisCandlestickChart(smp, xvar='Date', low='Low', open='Open', close='Close', high='High', 
                             options=list(legend='none', gvis.editor="Edit me!"))
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), display.mode='showcase')
```

Finally it is works... Here I post the screenshot inside below link as well. **However I would like to directly scrape the online dataset upon user's selection but not subset the existing dataset.**
http://cos.name/cn/topic/416837/#post-416909

Below I tried to scrap dataset directly upon react of users' choice. However the dataframe working fine without fit into shinyapp.

```
## Creating a parallel computing Cluster and support functions.
## Preparing the parallel cluster using the cores
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 16)
pkgs <- c('shiny','shinydashboard','magrittr','plyr','dplyr','googleVis','quantmod','TTR','lubridate','DT','purrr')
suppressMessages(require('BBmisc'))
suppressMessages(lib(pkgs)); rm(pkgs)

## Set the googleVis options first to change the behaviour of plot.gvis, so that only the chart 
##  component of the HTML file is written into the output file.
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')

tickers <- sort(c('BET', 'BOTB', 'BPTY', 'WMH', 'SPO', '888', 'NPT', 'PTEC', 'PCGE', 'TTR', 'GVC', 'WEB', 
                  'BOX', 'RNK', 'LAD', 'STR', 'LVS', 'TNI', 'WYNN', 'MGM', 'MPEL', 'MCRI', 'GXYEY', 'BYD', 
                  'GIGNY', 'CACQ', 'PENN', 'GEBHY', 'WYNMF', 'CWLDY', 'SCHYF', 'SKYZF', 'MCHVY', 'EGT', 
                  'GPIC', 'SGMS', 'NGCRF', 'TACBY', 'IGT', 'GDEN', 'ISLE', 'GLXZ', 'SJMHF', 'PDSSF', 'PNK'))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      titlePanel('Stock Price'),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          helpText('Select the stocks to examine. Information will be collected from Google/Yahoo finance.'),
          checkboxGroupInput('counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers), 
          actionLink('selectall', 'Select/Unselect All'),
          br(),
          br(),
          dateRangeInput('dates', 'Date range', start = '2013-01-01', end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
          checkboxInput('log', 'Plot y axis on log scale', value = FALSE),
          checkboxInput('adjust', 'Adjust prices for inflation', value = FALSE)),
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel( #tabBox
            tabPanel('Table', dataTableOutput('table1'), 
                     downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')),
            tabPanel('Chart', htmlOutput('gvis')))
        )))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
    else if(input$selectall%%2 == 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers)
    }else{
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'counter', 'Select counter(s)', choices = tickers, selected = tickers)
    }
  })

  getCounter <- function(){
    data <- na.omit(data.frame(Com=NA, Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA, Date=NA, Weekday=NA))
    data <- llply(input$counter, function(x) {
      y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
        tryCatch(suppressAll(na.omit(getSymbols(x, src = 'google', auto.assign = FALSE, 
                                        start = input$dates[1], end = input$dates[2]))), 
                 error = function(e) data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA)))); 
      if(nrow(na.omit(y))==0) {
        y = data.frame(Com=x, as.data.frame(
          tryCatch(suppressAll(na.omit(getSymbols(x, src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE, 
                                          start = input$dates[1], end = input$dates[2]))), 
                   error = function(e) data.frame(Open=NA, High=NA, Low=NA, Close=NA, Volume=NA))))
      }else{
        y %<>% mutate(Date=as.character(rownames(.)), Weekday=factor(weekdays(ymd(Date))));
        names(y) <- c('Com', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Date', 'Weekday')}; 
      y}, .parallel=TRUE) %>% rbind_all %>% tbl_df %>% 
      select(Date, Weekday, Com, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) %>% mutate(Com=factor(Com)) %>% na.omit
    return(data)
  }

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    data <- getCounter()
    data <- datatable(data, 
                    caption="Table 1.1.1 : Public Listed Companies Stock Price",
                    extensions = list("ColReorder"=NULL, "ColVis"=NULL, "TableTools"=NULL
                                      #, "FixedColumns"=list(leftColumns=2)
                    ), 
                    options = list(autoWidth=TRUE,
                                   oColReorder=list(realtime=TRUE), #oColVis=list(exclude=c(0, 1), activate='mouseover'),
                                   oTableTools=list(
                                     sSwfPath="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                                     aButtons=list("copy", "print",
                                                   list(sExtends="collection", sButtonText="Save",
                                                        aButtons=c("csv","xls")))),
                                   dom='CRTrilftp', scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                                   colVis=list(exclude=c(0), activate='mouseover')))
    return(dt)
  })

  output$gvis <- renderGvis({
    data <- getCounter()
    if(input$adjust) data <- adjust(data)
    if(input$log) data <- mutate(data, Low=log(Low), Open=log(Open), Close=log(Close), High=log(High))
    gvisCandlestickChart(data, xvar='Date', low='Low', open='Open', close='Close', high='High', 
                         options=list(legend='none', gvis.editor="Edit me!"))
  })
}

#'@ runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), display.mode='showcase')
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Magical Error: Unable find object Date]