# how to use scrollx in shiny DT (renderDataTable)

Tags: datatable, shiny, shiny-server, dt

I want use scrollx options in shiny DataTable since there are many field.
(refer : https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)

How can i use? I cant'n find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found! in [mainPanel unable work in Shiny Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359720/mainpanel-unable-work-in-shiny-dashboard)

Just add options list like bellow

```
output$actCam <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(summaryDay[campaignid %in% act_idx,], 
                  options = list(scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE))
    })
```